# CSS: gardient border + border-radius

Tags: css

Is it possible to create **gradient borders** combined with a **border radius**?

I created a button with an `::after` element

```
button{
    background: -webkit-gradient ...
}

button::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    background: rgba(16,20,28,1);
    border-radius: 40px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Which looks like:

[image: Ex1]

The problem is that the inner element should be transparent. If the `background-color` property of `button` is set to `transparent`, the button takes on the color (gardiet) of the `::after` element:

[image]

I have found the following picture on the internet where the inner body is transparent and the border is a gradient.

[image: Ex2]

There are multiple tricks to get such a border but these don't support the `border-radius`.

Comment: _“I have found the following picture on the internet”_ – yeah, so? For all we know, that might be an actual image drawn inside a graphics program, and not HTML/CSS at all. So how does this help the question at all …?

Comment: Possible solution could be using SVG though – either to draw the border in SVG directly, or by using an SVG filter to “cut out” the inner button part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A posibility, limited in support to modern browsers (all major browser except IE) and also limited to the colors that you can achieve, is to use mix-blend-mode, that can make gray look like transparent.

Also, some special properties to get the border, to begin with

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: solid 12px transparent;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(gray,gray), linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="test">TEST</div>
</div>
```